# Select sums of score for each player

Tags: mysql, sql

Asume simple table of score (player_id, score). How to select sum of score for each player? And limit the result olny to N highest sums.

```
player_id|score
---------------
      457|   20
      457|   25
      300|   50
      300|    5
      100|    1
```

If the N is 2 the result should be

```
player_id|score
---------------
      300|   55
      457|   45
```

Comment: `select user, max(score) as val from scores group by user order by val desc limit 10`

Answer (score 2):

First you need to group results, then order by grouped results and limit your result to 2 records (I assumed `players` table name):

```
select player_id, sum(score) score
from players
group by player_id
order by score desc
limit 2
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n68VJdcVXT2WVkVg9S2BfC/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 2 player_id, SUM(score) FROM score GROUP BY player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sum() group by and

For mysql   you can use limit

```
  select player_id, sum(score) score
  from my_table 
  group by player_id 
  order by score desc
  limit 2
```

for SqlServer you can use TOP 2

```
  select TOP 2 player_id, sum(score) score
  from my_table 
  order by score desc
  group by player_id
```